# Whose graveyard is "a graveyard"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Shadowfeed](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shadowfeed) card has following text:

> Exile target card from a graveyard. You gain 3 life.

Does it mean *my* graveyard, or *any* graveyard, including my opponents'?

Comment: 'A' graveyard...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any.

Your graveyard is a graveyard.
Your opponent's graveyard is a graveyard.
Cards in either graveyards are cards in a graveyard.

It would say ["your graveyard"](http://magiccards.info/mma/en/219.html) or ["an opponent's graveyard"](http://magiccards.info/wwk/en/48.html) otherwise.

Comment: Gotta love literalness.

Comment: Still has to be within your own game, though. No destroying cards in games you can see from your seat. :P

Comment: What  AlbeyAmakiir is saying is that only the players have a graveyard. If it's not in the game, it's not in a graveyard.

Answer (score 3):

The card doesn't specify which graveyard, so it can be *any* graveyard. That means that you can exile any card from your graveyard, one of your opponents' graveyards, or even one of your allies' graveyards in certain kinds of multiplayer games.

Answer (score 3):

It means you pick the graveyard. So, it could be your graveyard or one belonging to an opponent; i.e. any graveyard. If it were supposed to only apply to your or an opponent's graveyard, the card would say so.